# How does the code idiom for replacing part of a held expression work?

Tags: evaluation, replacement

I've seen this idiom used in different programs but never fully understand why it is necessary. Could someone explain? Is it still the recommended way to  replace some part of a held expression to its evaluated value? Is there an alternative method that uses more built-in functionality?

```
heldExpression /: lhs_ :> evaluate[rhs_] := lhs :> With[{tmp = rhs}, tmp /; True]
```

Comment: The earliest mention of that that I know of is at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/